# Google Sheets Lookup Struggles - Getting offset value from VLookup of a different sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, spreadsheet

The Struggle Bus is nearing capacity.

I'm trying to get an offset value from a vlookup, but I don't think it's possible.

[image: row data]

Doing a lookup on a different sheet using L123 as the reference to my schedule grid sheet:

[image: grid sheet]

I need the value from column A, but Vlookup doesn't like including column A in the range, and Match doesn't seem to like merged cells.

VLookup looks like this, and returns the value seen in column N in the data row:
`=VLOOKUP(L123,importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<sheetaddress>/","'Sunday'!B1:Q137"),1,false)`

So I can find the item, but I can't seem to get the table it's assigned (that's column A).  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

reverse it:

```
=VLOOKUP(L123, {IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sunday!B1:B137"), 
                IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sunday!A1:A137")}, 2, 0)
```